# How to move the extension 'Customers Who Bought This Also Bought' before the product details?

Tags: magento2, extensions

I am trying to move the bottom section up to the top above the tabs. Not sure how I am going to do this since the extension is handled in the backend. I tried moving it with all of the options here where it says block position:

[image]

[image]

Thankyou!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: what is the name of the block you want to move? And did you try <move element="" destination before="-" />?

Comment: wouldnt the block be called 'customers.who.bought.this.also.bought' ?

Comment: No I don't think so , but you can find it in `customers.who.bought.this.also.bought` extension under `view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`. If its possible can you share the content of the file with me?

Comment: Ahhh I found it in app/code/Aheadworks/Wbtab/Model/Source/CartPageBlock/Position.php

Comment: const CONTENT_TOP_VALUE = 'wbtab_content_top';

Comment: sorry was off work but did it really work?

Comment: @klict yes it did work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found my answer.

I checked at and edited at

```
app/code/Aheadworks/Wbtab/Model/Source/CartPageBlock/Positio‌​n.php
```